# Is relying on a few, large files, as dependencies efficient?

Tags: javascript, css, web

I am developing a web application with many 3rd party javascript and css dependencies. Since I discovered Node.js, bower, and gulp, finding and installing such dependencies has been a breeze.
However, I've been aggressively pursuing a policy of concatenating all my javascript into a single file, and ditto for all my stylesheets. After concatenating and minifying, my web application depends only on two fairly large files (main.js and main.css).
For reference, my main.js file is 1.6MB in size, and my main.css file is 261KB in size. Not huge by any means, but far larger than any one of the individual dependencies by themselves.
Is this optimal, or does the growing size of these files eventually outweigh the optimization gained by making fewer requests? Is there a scenario where this strategy would be a bad idea?

Comment: AFAIK, you are doing it right but I think it can be made more optimal. Are you using whole main.js and main.css on the loaded page at once? if not, then consider loading them asynchronously when necessary and load only related js and css stuff for the loaded page.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can read here to know more. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/rail?hl=en)

Comment: @Paulie_D Is it really, though? I mean, the matter of which approach is more optimal can be discussed, but ultimately it's not a matter of opinion. Either large files are more optimal, or they're not. I hope the question doesn't evoke mere opinion-based answers, but good fact-based ones like Sheepy's

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks for the link, I'll check it out! No, I can't say I am using it all all the time. You see, when I started developing the app, my decision to concatenate all my files was born as much from laziness as it was optimization. Instead of including scripts into my html files individually, I could run a simple task that concatenated my files and left the Html untouched. Now that the project has grown and load times increased, I'm beginning to question my decision, and that's why I'm here

Comment: 1.6MB for a minified JS file? Hot damn. That's a lot. I hope your website isn't going for a mobile-first approach. 1.6MB can take a loooong time to download on mobile connections.

Comment: @JonathanQuinth I can suggest a aspect like to keep the js and css files in module fashion and load them asynchronously when necessary. You can check module loaders like requirejs or webpack for this. I believe making the user to wait for short time with intervals is fine other than keeping him/her wait for long time on first page load.  BTW, I think integrating a module loader like webpack at this time is time taking process. So you can go with Sheepy's answer.

Comment: It is in my opinion...Optimal for who, under what circumstances, define optimal and what if your definition is different from someone elses? That's why it's opinion based or requires discussion....but opinions on the "topicness" will vary here.

Comment: @Paulie_D Understood. I still hope the question will remain open, because I'm sure I'll learn something, but I see your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Not consolidating resources incur network overhead.  But when the js gets so big, it should be split.

All major browsers [preload](http://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/) your script and css.
So, if you split your 1.6 MB js into 3, the browser will load all three and the css together in 4 connections.

You may think the total bandwidth is the same so why bother?  But it may be faster, because:

1. It draws more bandwidth from the server.
2. It draws more bandwidth from other programs / service.
3. It draws more bandwidth from other tabs in the same browser.
4. Parts can be parsed and perhaps executed when other parts are still downloading.
5. If you update only one of the parts, the other parts can be read from cache.

1.6MB is very big, and you should see speed improvement if you split it up.
But the sweet spot depends on a lot of factors, so you need to experiment to see what part size work best for you.

In fact, it is so big, you should defer the script, as Mr_Green commented.
Let your css and html go first, show a loading icon, and then load your big scripts.